# Google+ Api get user email

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-plus

I am creating a Sign Up With Google+ API. When inserting data into my Users table, I want to get the user's email. I get an error when trying to do that. My code looks like this:

```
var API_KEY = 'A*****';         

plus.people.get({
    auth: API_KEY,
    userId: req.body.userID
}, function (err, user) {
    if( err ) { res.json( JSON.stringify( err ) );  return; }
    console.log(user.emails);

    User.find({ where:{ social_id:req.body.userID, type: 2 } }).then( existingUser =>{              
    if( existingUser ) throw new Error('social_user_existing');
    if(!existingUser){
    User.build({
        username: user.displayName,
        social_id : req.body.userID, 
        social_token :req.body.token, 
        type : 2
        }).save();                      
    }                          
    }).then(function( new_g_user ){                 
        return res.json( rs.success({ username: user.displayName, user_id: user.id, jwt: new_g_user.getJwt() }) );
    }).catch(function(err){
        res.json( rs.errorCode(err.message) );
    });   
});
```

I tried to get the email of the user with user.emails and user.emails[0].value to get at least the value of the first email. Each time, the response was 'undefined'. I mention that user.kind is `'plus#person'`, not `"plus#personOpenIdConnect"`. Can this cause the response I get? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DalmTo mentioned, the API keys can be used to access public data. If you want to get access to the user private information you have to use OAuth.

Use the `OAuth2` class from [`googleapis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googlapis) to set up the authentication:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const CREDENTIALS = require("./credentials.json");

var googleAuth = new OAuth2(
  CREDENTIALS.web.client_id,
  CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret,
  CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
);
```

`credentials.json` is the file you can download from your Google app (the credentials section) which contains the application keys.

Once you get the access token, you need to do:

```
googleAuth.setCredentials({
  access_token: yourAccessToken
});
```

And finally, instead of using `auth: API_KEY` you will do `auth: googleAuth`.

```
plus.people.get({
    auth: googleAuth,
    userId: req.body.userID
}, function (err, user) {
    if( err ) { res.json( JSON.stringify( err ) );  return; }
    console.log(user.emails);
});
```

If everything goes well, you should be able to get the private information from the user.

Note that to access the emails, you need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope.

---

To get an access token for testing, you can use the OAuth playground:

1. Open https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
2. Enter the auth scopes you need, and then click the blue button:

   [image]

   It will make a couple of redirects.
3. In *Step 2* click the blue button again to exchange the authorization code into access tokens.

And now, you will see in the right side of the screen your `access_token`:

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.G....OEDi", 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "expires_in": 3600, 
  "refresh_token": "....hLA", 
  "id_token": ".....B1LGce02PMQHig"
}
```

You can use it for testing. When implementing OAuth2 in your app, you will need to set up the redirections, following the OAuth2 protocol rules.

Answer (score 2):

You are authencating using an API key so that means that you will only have access to public data.

Request

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/+lindalawton

response

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"Sh4n9u6EtD24TM0RmWv7jTXojqc/8CXX3KsOcUfAF5mmrG4vyB-YNig\"",
 "occupation": "Google Developer Expert, BIA Developer at Targit",
 "skills": "Experience primarily in regards Microsoft products, Visual Studio, Bids, C# and asp.net.  Past experience with PHP,JavaScript, MySQL and Linux.  In recent years I have begun focusing on Business Intelligence, Data Warehousing, SQL Server / Analysis Services / Integration Services.   Experience with OAuth2, Google Analytics API, Google Drive SDK.",
 "gender": "female",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://www.youtube.com/user/Atthena71",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Linda Lawton"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://twitter.com/LindaLawtonDK",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "lindalawtondk"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Stackoverflow / StackExchange"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit?trk=nav_responsive_sub_nav_edit_profile",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Linkedin"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://daimto.com/",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Daimto - data import tutorials"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://github.com/LindaLawton",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "GitHub - projects"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Google APIs .Net client - GitHub"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Google APIs .Net Samples - GitHub "
  },
  {
   "value": "https://developers.google.com/analytics/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Google Analytics"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://developers.google.com/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Google Developers"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://developers.google.com/experts/+LindaLawton",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Google Developer Expert - Linda Lawton"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "117200475532672775346",
 "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda"
 },
 "tagline": "Google Developer Expert 2014 - 2017",
 "braggingRights": "Extreme Beekeeper first to recorded an Hive inspection using Google Glass with out a veil on.",
 "aboutMe": "\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eBackground\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI have been working as an application developer since 1995. I have worked with a number of database systems Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and MySQL.  In recent years I have been mainly working with Microsoft products, Visual Studio, SSIS, and C#.   I the past I worked a lot with web development PHP, JavaScript, Ajax, power-builder,  Cobol and ASP.net.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eWhile I have done front end development in the past. I find working with backed development working on automated systems fascinating.    I have spent the last 5 years creating custom SSIS (Dlls), and services and APIs for the cloud (Azure).\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eGoogle API Addiction\u003c/b\u003e \u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eIn 2012 I began working with the Google APIs, starting with the Google Analytics API.  I learned to appreciate the fact that Google is so open and willing to give us access to their systems. I started blogging about how to use the APIs writing short tutorials with sample projects.   \u003ca href=\"http://www.daimto.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDaimto - Data Import Tutorials\u003c/a\u003e.   This along with my presents on a number of \u003ca href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDeveloper forms\u003c/a\u003e lead me to discovered by Google.  I became one of the first \u003ca href=\"https://developers.google.com/experts/+LindaLawton\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eGoogle Developer Experts for Google Analytics\u003c/a\u003e.  \u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI also help support the \u003ca href=\"https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eGoogle APIs client Library for .NET\u003c/a\u003e which provides simple, flexible, and powerful access to Google APIs such as Drive, YouTube, Calendar, Storage and Analytics.\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eLife\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI grew up in a small town in \u003ca href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth,_Massachusetts\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eMassachusetts\u003c/a\u003e, USA, I moved to \u003ca href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denmark\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDenmark \u003c/a\u003ein 1998 and have lived here since. I have a 22 year old daughter.  My hobbies include reading science fiction, painting, and gardening.   \u003c/div\u003e",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAdVM/sHkU9F-AwwQ/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "Newberry College",
   "title": "computer science",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "1991",
   "endDate": "1994",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "TARGIT",
   "title": "Business Intelligence Developer",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2011",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "name": "Logimatic",
   "title": "developer",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2008",
   "endDate": "2010",
   "primary": false
  }
 ],
 "placesLived": [
  {
   "value": "Aalborg Denmark",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "value": "Marathon Florida"
  },
  {
   "value": "Dartmouth Massachusetts"
  },
  {
   "value": "Ashford Connecticut"
  },
  {
   "value": "Nykøbing Mors Denmark"
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 2006,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/t2ViXd7ar3MeiOCeTe2g86Qd7wOnbRvuf3eTW3LPrs8jwBJwKS6gsC4KWhvbRSytJ5fsDne3sw=s630-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff",
   "height": 528,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": 0,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

Is only going to return what said user has set to public.   If their email is not public your not going to be able to see it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and complete answer! Please, tell me how can I get user's email address even if not public? Shall I replace API KEY with an object containing clientID and clientSecret? If affirmative, what should I do next?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to get someones email address if they do not have it set to public.  Google does not have an email address API this would be bad in so many ways.

Comment: According to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2  , saying: 'Before your application can access private data using a Google API ...', I can access private data if using OAuth. So, I guess, I have to change my code. Thank you!

Comment: if your using google signin try looking into the email scope.   That should give you access to the email address associated with their account.  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/